# Centrifuge-js read Public Channel with User Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

Hello I play poker in an MMO named [Torn City](https://www.torn.com/). I'm writing a user script for the game and it needs to detect when a player joins or leaves a poker table. I believe this is achievable as the chrome DevTools console prints statements when these actions are performed.

From what I've been able to figure out, the poker client is running off of [centrifuge-js](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifuge-js).

The console prints out the following when a player joins

[image: Player joins]

And when the player leaves

[image: Player leaves]

The only part of this I'm interested in is the message from chat data reading "joined the table" and "left the table" respectively. How do I pull these values? My user script already requires jQuery so a solution with javaScript or jQuery will work.

Additionally I can go through the Google Chrome Developer Tools and open centrifugeConnection.js I can post the code if it's needed, though I'm not sure of the legality of it as it's not my code.

Comment: look into making local modifications using devtools, which will let you easily wrap or replace the console log code, which you can find by clicking the citation in the message's upper right corner.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This allows me to add my own code to centrifugeConnection.js and detect those changes correct? How will this work with user-scripts? I plan on using tampermonkey to distribute the script later and the user's won't have edited centrifugeConnection.js files

Comment: i didn't know you need to distro, which makes it more complex. you need to add an event to `this._transport`, or if not reachable, wrap `WebSocket.prototype` to leach a handle to all created socket connections from your code.

Comment: I'll give this a shot thanks